# How do I add input controls dynamically using Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have a form in weather that would have had the condition User add as many lines he needs. He clicks a button and an input is added below the other.
I can do this using jQuery, but I would prefer to use the resources of Meteor. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, here is an example from one of my apps using the [underscore package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/underscore)

In the main template:

```
<template name="ask">
{{#each answerArray}} 
    {{>answer}} 
{{/each}}

<button id="addItem">Add item</button>
</template>

<template name="answer">
<div class="input-group pt10">
    <input class="form-control answer" maxlength="30" placeholder="Answer (max 30 chars)" name="answer" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger delButton" id="{{id}}" data-id="{{id}}" type="button">Delete</button>
    </span>
</div>
</template>
```

In the js file:

```
Template.ask.created = function () {
    Session.set('action', 'ask');
    answerArray = [ //adding at least two items but it could also be empty
        {
            id: Random.id(), //using this to give an unique id to the control
            value: ''
        },
        {
            id: Random.id(),
            value: ''
        }
    ];
    Session.set('answerArr', answerArray);
}
```

And the click event:

```
Template.ask.events = {
'click #addItem': function () {
    var answerArray = Session.get('answerArr');
    answerArray.push({
        id: Random.id() //just a placeholder, you could put any here
    });
    Session.set('answerArr', answerArray);
}
}
```

And finally the helper:

```
Template.ask.helpers({
answerArray: function () {
    var answerArray = Session.get("answerArr")

    while (answerArray.length < 2) { //i chose to have it between 2 and 6, you can remove these
        answerArray.push({
            id: Random.id() 
        })
    }
    while (answerArray.length > 6) { // maximum
        answerArray.pop();
    }
    Session.set('answerArr', answerArray);
    return answerArray;
}
}
```

This will reactively increase the number of inputs. After that, if you want to process the inputs you could do the following, on a submit form event or button click:

```
'click #saveQ': function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var arr = [];
    _.each($('.answer'), function (item) {
        if ($(item).val() != '')
            arr.push({
                answer: $(item).val(), //this you customize for your own purposes
                number: 0
            })
    });
```

And also if you want to delete an input from the page you can use:

```
Template.answer.events = {
'click .delButton': function (e) {
    var thisId = $(e.target).attr("id");

    var answerArray = Session.get('answerArr');

    var filteredArray = _.filter(answerArray, function (item) {
        return item.id != thisId;
    });

    Session.set('answerArr', filteredArray);
}
}
```

Comment: This works. The only problem i found was deleting an item. If i have items 1,2,3,4,5, when i delete number 3, it actually delete the data of number 5, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Might make sense, but you need to show me your code. I remember hitting something like that once, don't know how i fixed it though.

Comment: Well. the way i got around it was putting a "change" event to my input to update the "answerArr " array in Session every time there is a change. That way, when i remove an item, it still keeps the value from the other items.

Comment: @Rafael or AndreasFruth it would be gnarly if you could post your solutions to this problem :D I face the same one at the moment

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved it using these principles.. however I feel there should be another way.. I had to use selectors such as .children for my solution: score_name: item.children[0].children[0].value... It works, but not very elegant